# js: how to create a div that I can drop files on to upload

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Have this in CSS:

```
#drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}
```

and then a `div` in my HTML:

```
<div id="drop_zone"><span style="color: darkgray">Drop files here.</span></div>
```

I've previously written javascript to intercept the handler and to parse through files locally, but now I'm interacting with a Flask backend and want to just pass the files in as an upload event, bypassing a standard form:

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

Is there an easy way to do this in javascript?

Also, it would be great to do something in the style of Gmail, where it gives you a standard upload option (I've been looking into jasny's upload widget but have been having some heartburn with it) and then, when you drag a file onto the div, it gives you the option to drag-and-drop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you are asking for here is provided in a cross-browser upload library I maintain: [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  There's no sense in reinventing the wheel, IMHO.  Check out the readme and the demos and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: hey ray, is it possible to follow up offline with a few additional questions? not 100% sure how to hook this up to a flask endpoint correctly.

Comment: @fox I'm afraid I don't have enough resources to provide offline support at this point.  Plus, I'm not familiar with flask.  Please open up a new thread on SO here, be sure to tag it fine-uploader and flask and I'll try to give you a hand.